# What am I missing about the vuetify grid-system?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I am having issues with getting the vuetify grid-system to work properly. I have installed vuetify, added it as a plugin to my app and imported it into my file. When I use its `<v-container>` or `<v-row>`- tags, a grid shows up, so that should all be working. What is not working however, is the "linking" of columns to rows. I believe that I have the code set up correctly, as it is basically a copy of the tutorial-code on the vuetify website. When I run the file, the columns are children of the rows, as expected, but are shown below eachother, not next to eachother. I have two rows which I do expect to be shown below eachother, but I want the columns of each row to be shown horizontally to eachother, inside the row.

Here is how I want it to look like, it is a screenshot of an example from the vuetify docs:
[image]

What I end up with however, looks like this:
[image]

I will also provide my code here:

```
<template>
  <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
    <v-row
      v-for="n in 2"
      :key="n"
      :class="n === 1 ? 'mb-6' : ''"
      no-gutters>
      <v-col
        v-for="k in n + 1"
        :key="k">
        <v-card
          class="pa-2"
          outlined
          tile>
          {{ k }} of {{ n + 1 }}
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

I really hope someone can help me, as I am very stuck and feel like I have tried everything.
I appreciate every answer! :)

EDIT: I just saw that the console tells me that "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: `<v-col>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.". That seems strage to me, as there are indeed rows and columns shown on the rendered site. Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Did you wrap the entry point of your app in `<v-app>`?

Comment: The point is you haven't  properly used the `sm`, `md` or `lg` breakpoints property. Take a look at the code sample provided by Vuetify site and be aware that there a script section for this sample code there! [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#row-and-column-breakpoints)

Comment: Vuetify next is not production ready. However v-col should work if you registered vuetify

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestion! They didnt help me solve the problem directly, but definetely pushed me in the right direction! What I ended up doing is add the components manually to the "vuetify.js"-file that is located in the plugins folder. It now works as expected :)